# String comparisons and textfield actions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I just started working with Xcode today to make Cocoa applications.

I'm watching videos on YouTube to try and get me going. I'd like to start building Mac applications now that I've switched to one. I used to program in .NET on Windows.

Well I'm creating a small "login" window to begin with. In Xcode, I'm getting some type of error with this If statement. It's not really an error, but more like a warning. It works okay, but I want to make sure I'm doing this the right way. Basically all it does is check to make sure that the username and password fields have some content in them.

Keep in mind that this is seriously the first Objective-C code i've ever written in my life.

```
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController

NSString * quser = @"f";
NSString * qpass = @"f";

- (IBAction)checkforErrors:(id)sender {

        //the next couple of lines is where I'm getting the error msg...


        if (qpass == @"t") {
            if (qpass = @"t") {
            [label setStringValue:@"Username and Password are valid."];
            }
        }


}

- (IBAction)usernameEntered:(id)sender {

    quser = @"t";

}

- (IBAction)passwordEntered:(id)sender {

    qpass = @"t";

}
```

Am I even doing the variable stuff right?? I'm trying to go by my JavaScript and PHP knowledge to help me through this (even though they're completely different languages!! :P).

Another thing I want to ask. In Xcode it gives me the option to send the action on a textfield after text entry or on enter. The problem is, if you go an type in the password and go down and click the button to `checkforErrors`, it doesn't work. You have to click somewhere else and then click the button. Is there anyway to send the action "onTextChange?"

Also, if you have good resources to learn Objective-C/Cocoa I'd love to have them.

Comment: Strings are never compared with ==, use isEqualToString:

Answer (score 1):

Okay let's start with the easy bit:

```
    if (qpass == @"t") {
        if (qpass = @"t") {
        [label setStringValue:@"Username and Password are valid."];
        }
    }
```

There are two problems with these lines. Firstly, everything with a `*` in Objective-C is a pointer. When you compare with `==` you are comparing the location of the pointer, not the contents of the string. You want to use `isEqualToString:` instead.

Secondly, in your second `if` statement, you are doing an assignment. I'm also assuming you don't want to check for `@"t"` twice?

> > You have to click somewhere else and then click the button. Is there anyway to send the action "onTextChange?"

You want to take a look at [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), and `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` in particular. Also, some info on protocols can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1).

Lastly, some learning resources:
[Introduction to Objective-C on Treehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-objective-c)
[Apple's Getting Started guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Those are referenced objects you are working with, so any direct comparison would attempt to compare their logical addressed... which **is almost guaranteed not to work.** Seriously, the only way that could work is if both variables were uninitialized. As suggested, is the "isEqual" method.

Also, even if direct comparison was supported, 'qpass = @"t"' is an assignment, which actually would probably evaluate true, as it would evaluate qpass's address.

Comment: The `isEqual:` method will work but is slower than `isEqualToString:`, if you know they are both strings, the `isEqualToString:` method is better.

Comment: strings are different.  It's possible for two strings to share the same address if their contents are the same (that doesn't make it right at all to use ==, but still).